# Assistance related to Lua programming where Basic Calculator need to build using 3 operators addition, subtraction and multiple

Tags: lua

We had given below task

Create three function using Lua which can perform addition, subtraction and multiplication/

The program should be

Accept any number.
Check the operator + - *. If not the print "Invalid operand" and exit.
Accept two operands. if any operand not number print "Invalid operand" and exit. use - tonumber()
Perform the operation and print result.

We had written code as below which not working as expected , not sure where we went wrong, please guide us

```
local operators = {
    ["+"] = function(x,y) return x+y end,
    ["-"] = function(x,y) return x-y end,
    ["*"] = function(x,y) return x*y end
}

local function default()
    print "Invalid operand"
end

local num1 = io.read()
local num2 = io.read()
local operator = io.read()

local func (
 if operator == "+" then
   local add = tonumber(num1) + tonumber(num2)   
 end 
 if operator == "-" then
   local subtract = tonumber(num1) - tonumber(num2)
 end
 if operator == "*" then
   local multiply = tonumber(num1) * tonumber(num2)
 end
)
or default
print(func(num1,num2))
io.read()
```

Correct code is

```
local operators = {
  ["+"] = function (x, y) return x + y end,
  ["-"] = function (x, y) return x - y end,
  ["*"] = function (x, y) return x * y end,
}

local operator = operators[io.read()]
local num1 = tonumber(io.read())
local num2 = tonumber(io.read())

if num1 and num2 then
  if operator then
    print(operator(num1, num2))
  else
    print("Invalid operator")
  end
else
  print("Invalid operand")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors and doesn't make too much sense.

```
local func (
 if operator == "+" then
   local add = tonumber(num1) + tonumber(num2)   
 end 
 if operator == "-" then
   local subtract = tonumber(num1) - tonumber(num2)
 end
 if operator == "*" then
   local multiply = tonumber(num1) * tonumber(num2)
 end
)
or default
```

To define a local function you can write

```
local myFunction = function() end
```

or

```
local function myFunction() end
```

But not

```
local func()
```

As you define the function it can never be nil. So short-circuiting a function definition like

```
local default = function() end
local myFunction = function() end or default
```

doesn't make sense.

You should add instructions so the user knows what to enter befor you call io.read().

This part of your code is not used at all:

```
local operators = {
    ["+"] = function(x,y) return x+y end,
    ["-"] = function(x,y) return x-y end,
    ["*"] = function(x,y) return x*y end
}
```

Also your function `func` does nothing but creating local variables which are not used.

The function does not return a value so printing it's return value like `print(func(num1, num2))` won't print a result as intended.

You also fail to check if the user actually entered valid characters like numbers or operators. This will cause Lua errors if the user inputs something else.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `operators` table. Instead of setting `operator` to the string that a user inputs, set it to the function that the user needs. If the user inputs an operator that is not in the table, `operator` will be set to `nil`:

```
local operator = operators[io.read()]
```

Similarly, set `num1` and `num2` directly to the numbers that will be operands instead of setting them to user input strings:

```
local num1 = tonumber(io.read())
local num2 = tonumber(io.read())
```

If `tonumber` can't convert the user inputs into numbers, `num1` or `num2` will be set to `nil`.

You can use the fact that invalid inputs are given `nil` values to validate the input. You don't really need the `default()` function to simply report that input is bad, and I did not use this in the final code below. If you did want to remove this reporting to functions you should probably at least distinguish between bad operands and bad operators:

```
local function bad_operand()
  print("Invalid operand")
end

local function bad_operator()
  print("Invalid operator")
end
```

Now you just need to check whether the arguments are valid, and whether the operator is valid, and if so perform the calculation. Here is the code:

```
local operators = {
  ["+"] = function (x, y) return x + y end,
  ["-"] = function (x, y) return x - y end,
  ["*"] = function (x, y) return x * y end,
}

local num1 = tonumber(io.read())
local num2 = tonumber(io.read())
local operator = operators[io.read()]

if num1 and num2 then
  if operator then
    print(operator(num1, num2))
  else
    print("Invalid operator")
  end
else
  print("Invalid operand")
end
```

Here are some sample runs:

```
~/code/lua/scratch $ lua calc.lua 
3
4
-
-1
~/code/lua/scratch $ lua calc.lua 
7
5
*
35
~/code/lua/scratch $ lua calc.lua
3
/
/
Invalid operand
~/code/lua/scratch $ lua calc.lua
3
4
/
Invalid operator
```

The nice thing about using the `operators` table is that we can now add operators to the table to extend the functionality of the program without making any other changes:

```
local operators = {
  ["+"] = function (x, y) return x + y end,
  ["-"] = function (x, y) return x - y end,
  ["*"] = function (x, y) return x * y end,
  ["/"] = function (x, y) return x / y end,
  ["//"] = function (x, y) return x // y end,
}
```

Testing the new operators:

```
~/code/lua/scratch $ lua calc.lua 
3
4
/
0.75
~/code/lua/scratch $ lua calc.lua 
7
3
//
2
```